# python polymorphism concepts example

Tags: python

I have gone through many links but what is the easiest way of understanding polymorphism using python..Are there any simple examples..From my understanding polymorphism is a concept where an object can take more than once form..Can any one let me know of any simple examples rather than complicated

http://swaroopch.com/notes/python_en-object_oriented_programming/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a good and simple example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Example

*Example copied from wikipedia article:*

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):    # Constructor of the class
        self.name = name
    def talk(self):              # Abstract method, defined by convention only
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclass must implement abstract method")

class Cat(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Meow!'

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        return 'Woof! Woof!'

animals = [Cat('Missy'),
           Dog('Lassie')]

for animal in animals:
    print(animal.name + ': ' + animal.talk())


# prints the following:
# Missy: Meow!
# Lassie: Woof! Woof!
```

BTW python uses *duck typing* to achieve polymorphism, search for that phrase if you want to know more.

Answer (score 1):

Static languages primarily depend upon inheritance as the vehicle for implement polymorphism. 
Dynamic languages on the other hand depend upon duck typing. [Duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) supports polymorphism without using inheritance. In this context you need the same set of relevant methods to be implemented in each of the extension classes.

From wikipedia duck typing page

```
 class Duck:
    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaaaaack!")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The duck has white and gray feathers.")

class Person:
    def quack(self):
        print("The person imitates a duck.")
    def feathers(self):
        print("The person takes a feather from the ground and shows it.")
    def name(self):
        print("John Smith")

def in_the_forest(duck):
    duck.quack()
    duck.feathers()

def game():
    donald = Duck()
    john = Person()
    in_the_forest(donald)
    in_the_forest(john)

game()
```

Try to think in objects with a protocol (a set of methods) and interchangeability between those with the same protocol.

[duck typing definition](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) from python.org :

> A programming style which does not look at an object’s type to
>   determine if it has the right interface; instead, the method or
>   attribute is simply called or used (“If it looks like a duck and
>   quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.”) By emphasizing interfaces
>   rather than specific types, well-designed code improves its
>   flexibility by allowing polymorphic substitution. Duck-typing avoids
>   tests using type() or isinstance(). (Note, however, that duck-typing
>   can be complemented with abstract base classes.) Instead, it typically
>   employs hasattr() tests or EAFP programming.